# Unable to Connect to Database using Custom Connection String with ODBC.jl

Tags: odbc, julia

I'm having trouble connecting to a database with the ODBC.jl package. I can't tell if the problem is with my setup (more likely) or the package. The problem is that ODBC.jl can't seem to locate the correct ODBC driver.

```
> using ODBC
> ODBC.listdrivers()
  /path/to/generic/odbc/
```

But I need to use a different driver than the one picked up from above.

I'm trying to use a custom connection string as follows:

```
>ODBC.DSN("DRIVER=path/to/driver/i/want;SERVER=myserver;USER=myuser;PASSWORD=mypass;DATABASE=somedb;")
```

which returns this:

```
[ODBC] IM002: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
ERROR: ODBC.ODBCError("ODBC.API.SQLDriverConnect(dbc,window_handle,conn_string,out_conn.ptr,BUFLEN,out_buff,driver_prompt) failed; return code: -1 => SQL_ERROR                                                    ")
```

My understanding is that I should be able to specify the driver as done above, but this does not give the desired connection.

I have .odbc.ini and .odbcinist.ini files set-up in my home directory, which I believe are working correctly. I'm on a Suse enterprise distro. When connecting via `isql` i have no problems.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ODBC seems pretty broken at the moment tbh. I can't even get it to install on any julia version on my machine. You may just want to try another connection manager and save yourself the hassle ...

Comment: one thing to try, maybe if you wrap your path in escaped quotes?, i.e.  `>ODBC.DSN("DRIVER=\"path/to/driver/i/want\"; ... )`

Comment: Thanks. This does not work. It seems it does not matter what i put in for the path to my driver. The same error is always returned, even if a non-real path is used. - JM

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou any recommendations for a connection manager? I need to access some oracle and IBM databases.

Comment: sorry, I don't know much personally, but I did spot an alternative "JDBC" package in pkg.julialang.org, and judging from the 'tests' it seems like it might be a bit more promising.

Comment: There also seem to be specific MySQL and SQLite packages

Comment: The JDBC.jl package works pretty well, even if I say so myself. However, you will need Java installed, and will need to download the JDBC driver for your database. Once you do that, it's pretty smooth.